# How NHibernate keeps track of DETACHED Object?

Tags: nhibernate

We can traverse the state of Detached object to Persistent state by either using Update() 
or SaveorUpdate() etc. This means that nHibernate keeps track of Detached object somehow. I first thought it might save detached object in memory.But when i came across the statement I boggled:

> you can immediately Evict() each object after it has been processed
>   (while iterating through a query result), ***and thus prevent memory
>   exhaustion.***     Ref: NHibernate in Action

*provided that: Evict() is used to traverse from Persistent to Detached object.*

In the above statement : "**and thus prevent memory exhaustion.**" gives a notion as if 
Detached objects are not maintaned in memory. Where else then?

Comment: Does it mean 'first level cache' by memory?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, `Evict` removes the entity from the first level cache.

"Detached" just means that the object is not associated with a session.   It is not in the first level cache of any session.

`SaveOrUpdate` adds the object to the first level cache and schedules it to be inserted or updated on the next `Flush`.

Comment: So how does NHibernate keeps track of Detached object(as it is not in first level cache) I also came across another statement saying :Persistent instances are stored in the second-level cache in a disassembled form. While i was thinking they are stored in first level cache. Where am i wrong?